# Listing all *.jpg files in all sub directory and copy to new folder

Tags: php, copy, global-variables, rename, move

I build a custom Photon Weather station with all the bells and whistles. Final step is to install a solar powered camera that will upload photos to one of my servers and then pass it through to the other weather websites.

My problem is that I have no control on how the camera is uploading the files to the FTP. Basically it creates a master directory and then a sub directory with the time. Example `\\20203012\18\image.jpg`

My problem:
I need to scan the directory and sub directory for any *.jpg files and then move them to a different directory.

Not very clued up on PHP, but managed to get this working with a single directory. Code below:

```
rename(reset(glob("/home/public_html/old_directory/*.jpg")), "/home/new_directory/weather.jpg");
```

Is there any easy way to amend the above to look into all directories? Playing with a recursive function to see if this can assist me.

Comment: Is it always only one file or could it be multiple files?

Comment: Could be multiple files but do not mind of I can copy the latest file over to the new directory

Answer (score 0):

If it's just one file at a time, you could do something like:

```
$files = glob('/home/public_html/*/*.jpg');
rename(reset($files), '/home/new_directory/weather.jpg');
```

If it's multiple files at a time, then you could do something like:

```
$files = glob('/home/public_html/*/*.jpg');
foreach ($files as $file) {
    rename($file, '/home/new_directory/' . basename($file));
}
```

The second one would retain the original file name, so unless you have another way of naming those files so they don't overwrite each other, that'd be the best way to keep them separate. You'd have to watch out for collision though. If two files with the same filename are in two different directories, then you'd overwrite the first with the second.

Although, now that I realize it, this would create a problem in that it would also pick up images from your `new_directory`. You'd have to have your new uploads go to a subfolder that would avoid this. For example:

```
$files = glob('/home/public_html/upload_directory/*/*.jpg');
rename(reset($files), '/home/new_directory/weather.jpg');
```

Or for multiple

```
$files = glob('/home/public_html/upload_directory/*/*.jpg');
foreach ($files as $file) {
    rename($file, '/home/new_directory/' . basename($file));
}
```

If you take the time to use recursion, you'd have better control over that sort of thing.

Comment: Hi Lawrence. Thank you so much mate. Playing with your code and seems to be working fine. Can't believe it was so simple. Was looking at the variable / wildcard to show a directory and notice it was just a simple "*" Thank you again and have a awesome new year.

Comment: Thanks @JakesOosthuizen, please mark the answer with a check if it solved your problem.